# Having trouble with changing an array position and displaying contents dynamically with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Array of Objects, with each object containing an Array of strings. I am using the ng-repeat to list all the strings, and have a button that should change to the next set of strings(by changing the object selected in the outermost array). Here is my code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizRadioButton.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quizAngularJs.js"></script>
<title>American History Quiz</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="questionCtrl">
        <form>
            <h1>{{question}}</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="choice in choices"><input type="radio" name = "answer">{{choice}}</li>
                    <li>{{count}}</li>
                </ul>
            <button ng-click= "upCount()">Submit Form</button>
            <button id='goBack'>Go Back</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function questionCtrl($scope){
var allQuestions = [....];
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.question = allQuestions[$scope.count].question;
$scope.choices = allQuestions[$scope.count].choices;

$scope.upCount = function(){
    $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
};
}
```

Each object in the array looks something like this

```
{
 question: "question A",
 choices: ["choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"],
 correct answer: 0
}
```

I did check to make sure count is updating, and it is. If the count is updating shouldn't the view update with it? I have also tried this for my function but still couldn't get it to work.

```
$scope.upCount = function(){
    $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    $scope.question = allQuestions[$scope.count].question;
    $scope.choices = allQuestions[$scope.count].choices;
};
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/wwhrJ/

Comment: So it turns out that setting the properties again in the function will make it work. I don't know why it wasn't working before. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have **allQuestions** inside the scope. I dont think you need two separate modules just to track the current question. **count** alone should serve the purpose.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function questionCtrl($scope){
    $scope.allQuestions = [....];
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.upCount = function(){
        /* make sure index don't run out of range */
        if($scope.allQuestions[$scope.count + 1])
            $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    };
    $scope.upCount = function(){
        /* make sure index don't run out of range */
        if($scope.allQuestions[$scope.count - 1])
            $scope.count = $scope.count - 1;
    };
}
```

And then in your HTML you could simply do:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="questionCtrl">
        <form>
            <h1>{{allQuestions[count].question}}</h1>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="choice in allQuestions[count].choices">
                    <input type="radio" name = "answer">{{choice}}</li>
                <li>{{count}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button ng-click= "upCount()">Submit Form</button>
            <button id='goBack'>Go Back</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. None of the strings in my array show up when doing this. Can you put other variables(the count) in the ng-repeat directive? All of my data is in the same module, and while I may be overlooking a more concise way to code this I cannot see why it isn't working. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes you can have a scope variable inside ng-repeat. Its perfectly valid. I suggest doing: **$scope.allQuestions** instead of **var allQuestions**.